# ros-ign-bridge not publishing CameraInfo

Tags: ros-noetic, ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I'm using Gazebo Fortress compiled from sources on Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic

When running `roslaunch ros_ign_gazebo_demos rgbd_camera_bridge.launch`

If I add a Camera view in RViz I get the warning CameraInfo not published.

Is this considered a normal behavior?

If not, how can I fix this?

EDIT:
I've figured out the following: In the Gazebo GUI, add the `Image Display` plugin, then select the depth image. The message will then be published on the associated Gazebo topic.

My question now is: How do I get the data to be published without using the GUI?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28653/ros-ign-bridge-not-publishing-camerainfo/) by [alex-ssom](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/107491/alex-ssom/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For whom ever might read this.

There was a bug in gz-sensors.
I opened an [issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/issues/307) and contributed a [PR](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/pull/308) that hopefully will have been merged by the time you read this.

---

Originally posted by [alex-ssom](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/107491/alex-ssom/) with karma: 16 on 2023-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0